# Scheduled method aplication to deploy at appharbor.com

Tags: c#, scheduled-tasks, appharbor

A while ago I've wrote an application that crawlers data from several websites, parses the data into specific format and sends this data to specific email address.

The app was executed x times a day via windows task scheduler.

Now I want to deploy this app to appharbor (i am not sure if it's possible to deploy console or library applications).

How can I schedule method executions via code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're working on adding background tasks to AppHarbor (it will be in the form of running console applications that you push). If the task doesn't take too long (eg. less that ~90 seconds), doing it in a controller is a viable workaround. You can use a service like [MomentApp](http://momentapp.com/) to trigger your crawler.

Comment: Can I use this MomentApp with my console app that I'll push to appharbor?

Comment: Not currently, you'll have to move your console app code into the website. We should have background workers done soon, so you might also just want to wait.